# I want to add logs and screen shot using extentreports-cucumber4-adapter

Tags: selenium, cucumber, extentreports

I am working on Selenium Cucumber project. I am using below versions:

- Cucumber-core 4.2.0
- Cucumber-java 4.2.0
- Cucumber-junit 4.2.0
- extentreports-cucumber4-adapter 1.0.7

I am able to generate an HTML report. However, I want to know how to add screenshot and logs using the extentreports-cucumber4-adapter

```java
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = <PATH>,
glue = {"testcases.periscope"},plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:", "json:target/cucumber-report.json","html:target/Report.html"})
//@Category(Example.class)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to add log message or screen shot to a test step, follow this approach.
Create a static report class and add your custom log methods like this,

```
@AfterStep
public static void addStepLog(String Message)
{
ExtentCucumberAdapter.addMessageToTestStep(Message);
}
```

You have to customize the ExtentCucumberAdapter class and add some static log methods to make use of thread level step info.

Public static synchronized void addMessageToTestStep(String Message)
{

stepTestThreadLocal.get().info(Message);
}

```
Public static synchronized void addScreenShotToTestStep(String Message)
{

stepTestThreadLocal.get().embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    }
```

Comment: I just needed to use `ExtentCucumberAdapter.addMessageToTestStep` instead of `Reporter.addStepLog` as I was using w Cucumber 1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add screen shots using **extentreports-cucumber4-adapter v1.0.7** but same could not happen in **v1.0.6**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Now let's say we want to add screen shot when a test case gets failed so we could follow below code in hooks -

```
@After
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
        if(scenario.isFailed()){
            byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)DriverManager.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
        }
      }
```

If we want to print something in the report we can use **scenario.write("message");**